# Construct bitset from array of integers

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

It's easy to construct a `bitset<64>` from a `uint64_t`:

```
uint64_t flags = ...;
std::bitset<64> bs{flags};
```

But is there a good way to construct a `bitset<64 * N>` from a `uint64_t[N]`, such that `flags[0]` would refer to the lowest 64 bits?

```
uint64_t flags[3];
// ... some assignments
std::bitset<192> bs{flags};  // this very unhelpfully compiles
                             // yet is totally invalid
```

Or am I stuck having to call `set()` in a loop?

Comment: Do you mean to take the lowest 8 bits from every `uint64_t`? And in which order?

Comment: @Wintermute Oops. I want all the bits. `flags[0]` would be the lowest 64 bits.

Comment: Maybe something like `constexpr std::size_t FLAGS_SIZE = 3; uint64_t flags[FLAGS_SIZE]; std::bitset<64 * FLAGS_SIZE>();` ?

Comment: std::bitset has no conversion accepting an array of elements (where elements is the under-laying std::bitset type). In my point of view it is a failure as std::vector<bool> is.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it so unreasonable to want to be able to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::bitset` has no range constructor, so you will have to loop, but setting every bit individually with `std::bitset::set()` is underkill. `std::bitset` has support for binary operators, so you can at least set 64 bits in bulk:

```
  std::bitset<192> bs;

  for(int i = 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    bs <<= 64;
    bs |= flags[i];
  }
```

**Update:** In the comments, @icando raises the valid concern that bitshifts are O(N) operations for `std::bitset`s. For very large bitsets, this will ultimately eat the performance boost of bulk processing. In my benchmarks, the break-even point for a `std::bitset<N * 64>` in comparison to a simple loop that sets the bits individually and does not mutate the input data:

```
int pos = 0;
for(auto f : flags) {
  for(int b = 0; b < 64; ++b) {
    bs.set(pos++, f >> b & 1);
  }
}
```

is somewhere around `N == 200` (gcc 4.9 on x86-64 with libstdc++ and `-O2`). Clang performs somewhat worse, breaking even around `N == 160`. Gcc with `-O3` pushes it up to `N == 250`.

Taking the lower end, this means that **if you want to work with bitsets of 10000 bits or larger, this approach may not be for you.** On 32-bit platforms (such as common ARMs), the threshold will probably lie lower, so keep that in mind when you work with 5000-bit bitsets on such platforms. I would argue, however, that somewhere far before this point, you should have asked yourself if a bitset is really the right choice of container.

Comment: If bs is bitset<N*64>, then shift is an `O(N)` operation, so the overall loop is an `O(N^2)` operation.  Nobody noticed this?

Comment: @Barry, what you said, "Or am I stuck having to call set() in a loop?", is actually a better solution than this.  You accepted an O(N^2) solution given you have an O(N) solution yourself, which is weird.

Comment: That's a good point for large bitsets. I doubt the break-even point would be reached for a 192-bit bitset where the shift involves (on a PC) two machine words, but at some point it would. Let me go benchmark for a moment.

Comment: @icando Benchmark results are in; break-even above 10 kbits. I noted your concern and when it becomes relevant in the answer; it'll be good to have there if someone comes along who ponders abusing `std::bitset` in this way. For sane use cases, though, I'm not convinced that the threshold will ever be reached.

Comment: @Wintermute Cool. I'm dealing with pretty small `N`s and was mainly interested in code clarity rather than performance, so win-win! Also, <3 Neuromancer.

Answer (score -1):

If initializing from range is important, you might consider using std::vector

It does have constructor from pair of iterators